# Remove Blank space on right side from wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Just finished building a site for my company at http://www.thefunnyglobe.com/, and I'm noticing a strange issue. it have very large blank space on right hand side. Can anyone help? Can't figure it out.

Comment: You really need to learn HTML & CSS properly

Comment: It's your listed `div.content` elements. `1100px` wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width: 1100px` from the `.content` class.  Most likely, you're using `class="content"` for your list items as well as the page.  You should probably rename one of the classes.